# Filtering a views result two month ago from now

Tags: 7, views

I building a view with a date filter. How do I filter the nodes to the ones that have been created between the date I select and two months earlier?

I tried with a relative date value, but I do not know how I should set it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and enable the *Date Views* module which is part of the Date project. In your view, expose the date field, and select the *Between* operator with two dates (*Start date* and *End date*).

> [image: screenshot]